# Where do Stormtroopers come from?

Tags: star-wars

So in the Star Wars universe, Jango Fett is killed. Because he is the source of the genetic material for the clones, they would need to find a new source. However, after the clones kill off the Jedi and the Empire rises to power, there seems to be no lack of Stormtroopers, whom I am assuming are just mainly ex-Clone troopers.

Because all of the Stormtroopers are humanoid, the empire could not just be using any alien species they find. Are they using cloning still? Or are they just recruiting? And if they are cloning, whose genetic material are they using?

Comment: When a mummy trooper and a daddy trooper love each other very much...

Comment: When assuming ALL stormtroopers are EX-clonetroopers, you forgot that Luke was 19 when A New Hope Begins. Do we know how long the clones USABLE life expectancy is? Does accelerated growth shorten it? They would be near 40 in human years WITHOUT acceleration. Maybe old-age is why the stormtroopers aim is so bad? Or did Vader order them all to miss ON PURPOSE so he could follow his son to the hidden rebel base? Maybe he planned on capturing and converting him even then? (Also not part of official cannon, but it could be a good "Back to the Future 2" style remake? George? My name in the credits?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Says Wookiepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Stormtrooper):

> Stormtroopers were the elite soldiers of the Galactic Empire.
>
> [...]
>
> By the end of the Clone Wars in 19 BBY, the Galactic Republic was reorganized into the first Galactic Empire. As a result, the Grand Army was reformed into the Stormtrooper Corps and the clones were renamed "stormtroopers."
>
> [...]
>
> However, the stormtrooper ranks would cease to be dominated by Fett's progeny after the Battle of Kamino in 12 BBY.
>
> [...]
>
> By the time the Galactic Civil War began in earnest, Jango Fett's clones were heavily supplanted by clones based on a variety of templates around 9 BBY, followed shortly after by enlisted Humans.

Answer (score 3):

Luke wanted to "join the Imperial academy" So they were obviously hiring and training TIE-pilots at least. Most navy officers are promoted from the ranks of the enlisted. You have to fly a TIE-fighter without crashing before someone will trust you with a Star-Destroyer. None of the Admirals Vader force-choked looked much like Jango.

There were also rumors of Solo once being a stormtrooper, but not caring for the politics, esp over the treatment of wookies, which led to him "freeing the slaves" in a self-started rebellion. This story also explains Chewie's dedication to Han. I believe I heard that one of the MANY side stories published covers this part of his history (although not a part of official cannon).

Han's knowledge of "imperial protocol" for dumping garbage before jumping to hyperspace could have been gained from a previous accidental sighting, but this was another possible source of the rumor.

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chewbacca in the section "Life under the Empire", it covers how Han was a TIE Lieutenant who originally attacked Chewbacca. Chewie was caught and sentenced to be whipped to death, at which point Han saved his life.

Comment: There are other ways Stormtroopers are "acquired" as referenced in the new movie. No spoilers here, but it mentions their assigned code numbers as well.